# Populate a list from an xml file with attributes of the elements

Tags: javascript

Hi,

I have a xml file that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sendSound enable="true" autoPlay="true">
    <item name="Gasp for surprise" src="flashsound/gasp.mp3"></item>
    <item name="Giggle" src="flashsound/hehe.mp3"></item>
    <item name="Say hello" src="flashsound/hello.mp3"></item>
</sendSound>
```

I want to get each one of the items NAMES so it would go like this:

```
Gasp for surprise
Giggle
Say hello
```

This is my code

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "demo.xml", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("sendSound");
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    var names = user.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        alert(names[j].childNodes[0].getAttribute("name"));
    }
}
```

but I dont even get the alerts. What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it stands, as you are simply dumping your code and asking why it doesn't work. Please clarify what is meant by "I can't get it work". What happens when you run it?

Comment: nothing, thats what happens.

Comment: Cool, time to learn how to use a debugger!

Comment: Great idea, I have firefox devtools and nothing shows on the console...

Comment: The console is not the debugger. Use the Debugger tab to add breakpoints to your code to determine what each line is doing.

Comment: I had it fixed. Thank you anyway for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

parse it with `DOMParser()` and `parser.parseFromString()` and loose `.childNodes[0]`

( replace `myXml` with your `request.responseXML` )

```js
var myXml = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <sendSound enable="true" autoPlay="true">
        <item name="Gasp for surprise" src="flashsound/gasp.mp3"></item>
        <item name="Giggle" src="flashsound/hehe.mp3"></item>
        <item name="Say hello" src="flashsound/hello.mp3"></item>
    </sendSound>`;
    
    parser = new DOMParser();
    var xml =  parser.parseFromString(myXml,"text/xml");
    
    
    var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("sendSound");
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        var names = user.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
            console.log(names[j].getAttribute("name"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, seems like I just had to lose the childNodes[0] part

Comment: @CainNuke glad i could help :)

Comment: @rmlan i added the `parser` for the sake of the snippet to work, if you think it's unnecessary, feel free to post a different answer.

Comment: A little problem I came across. I uploaded the file to the server but I get an error that says xml is null. Why is that?

Comment: that's a problem for another question, my post answers the question you posted with a working snippet, you'll need to post that in another question with enough details to get an adequate answer.

Comment: but my question was for getting the data from an external xml file and in your answer the data is in-file. How you do it from an external file?

Comment: @Taki I read your answer too quickly and did not know that the DOMParser returned the exact same type of document that responseXML did. My apologies. I agree that the second problem mentioned would require a separate question.